# How to fix Osintgram's error 403 with error_title "You've Been Logged Out"?

Tags: python, http-status-code-403

When using [Datalux/Osintgram](https://github.com/Datalux/Osintgram), the `main.py` shows error 403 you have been logged out.

I tried to change my config/username password and credentials but none of it works.

What do i have to do if there is a problem like this in my Linux terminal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We request that you always **include** your errors, code, and instructions as **text**, and [not just a **description** or image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Have you done some research on the web, e.g. directly on GitHub in Osintgram's issues? Found [i have been logged out what should i do · Issue #590 · Datalux/Osintgram · GitHub](https://github.com/Datalux/Osintgram/issues/590), which might help.